# How to modify CSS with jQuery where two ids are next to each other

Tags: jquery, css

Would greatly appreciate some help with this.

I've got this html:

```
<div id="shopper_approved">
    <div id="sa_header">
        <img id="sa_close" class="sa_close" src="xbutton.gif">
        <span id="sa_header_text"> Thank You for Your Order </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've got this CSS:

```
#shopper_approved #sa_header { padding: 20px 0 0 30px}
```

I'm unable to modify it as it's loaded externally, but I'd like to change the padding after it's loaded.

I'm not sure how to do this with jQuery, when I try this it doesn't work:

```
$('#shopper_approved, #sa_header').css('padding-left','0px');
```

That changes the padding of shopper_approved and sa_header to 0px, but that is overridden by the css styling.

Comment: So `#class2` is a child of `#class1`, right? I mean, that's what your CSS suggests.

Comment: In your CSS rule, Its look like #class2 is the child element of #class1. is it right?

Comment: Post your HTML so we can see if your selector is correct. Most likely you can just use `$('#class2').css('padding-left','0px');`

Comment: #class2 suggests its an id, whereas the name suggests its a class. Please tell us what the element really is in the dom.

Comment: Please post your HTML so we can help you properly

Comment: please update your question instead of posting code in the comments and please post the HTML that has the id and classes that you are manipulating with your css, thx

Comment: i think you need to provide what you have done when you ask first time to get best answer for question. now you have updated your question.  and id name also changed.

Comment: Apologies for this, my first time posting a question here.

Comment: i have updated my answer please checkout.

Comment: My code works in fiddle, so it must be something else that is causing this to happen. I'll have to look more into the styling.

Answer (score 1):

-----------------After question update--------------------------

As per your updated question i have make new [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xr5c8d78/) with html,css provided by you and its working fine.

you may be not using `ready` function of jquery.

----------------------Before question update----------------------

I have make [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pyvn8m0k/5/) and its working fine.

**HTML** : [As you have not added html code in question, i have prepare from my side for sample]

```
<div id="class1">
    <div id="class2">
    Testing

    </div>

</div>

<input type="button" value="change padding" id="btn"/>
```

**css**

```
#class1 #class2 { padding: 120px 40px 0 130px}
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#btn").click(function(){


 $('#class1 #class2').css('padding-left','300px');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using the ready of jquery and the code is firing, I've checked in Chrome debugger but the padding doesn't change. sa_header padding changes to 0px but it is overridden by the css styling.

Comment: $('#shopper_approved, #sa_header').css('padding-left','0px'); here you are changing padding to 0 for both id as its separate by comma

Answer (score -1):

Hello dear your code is true bu you have problem in event 
first i will explain 
in jquery window.load and document.ready
both are diffrent
so if you want to change padding after page load then write this code under section of window.load any where writen in your page
Before coling of } this

```
   $(window).load(function(){
    setTimeOut(function(){
      $('#class1').css('padding-left','0px');
      //for one
      $('#class1, #class2').css('padding-left','0px');
      //for two
    },500)
  });
```

Comment: I really can't see how setTimeout would be a good solution to this problem

Comment: just for clarification 
i this you want this function when your some page is load on any action right then put this on success of page load

Comment: I'm not confuse and I'm not the question maker ... but your solution is just wrong ... if the problem is the dom rendering time, then he should use event listeners, not setTimeout

Comment: you have demo link then share with me or html